# jQuery html() converting braces to html entities (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically:

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="foo"><img src="/foo/bar/{var}/foo" alt="{var}"></div>
```

When calling (using jQuery in Firefox):

```
$("#foo").html()
```

I get:

```
<img src="/foo/bar/%7Bvar%7D/foo" alt="{var}">
```

My desired output is:

```
<img src="/foo/bar/{var}/foo" alt="{var}">
```

What's going on here? Any tips for how to resolve this?

I guess I'd be surprised if the solution was to use regex to undo the HTML entities conversion.  Using parens instead of braces seems to cause the same result (with different HTML entities).

**Edit**: I tried this using square brackets (`[` and `]`), and unlike parens and braces the brackets are not converted to HTML entities.  Do parens and braces have some special meaning here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use the javascript unescape function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

Comment: Thanks -- this is useful but as with regex this would unescape any intended HTML entities, though `unescape` is substantially better than any regex solution.

Comment: `unescape` should work perfectly and decode everything correctly.  I did a quick test with `<div id="foo"><img src="/foo/bar/{var}/foo" alt="{var}" />&amp;</div>` and `unescape($("#foo").html())` returns that literal string as it appears in source

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `&#123;` for `{` and `&#125;` for `}` in your HTML? That should prevent the curly braces from being interpreted by Javascript.